# java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError trying to use Quartz with Spring

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

I'm trying to start using Quartz. I'm trying to do a simple sample app, but i'm getting this error: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError
I hope someone can help me solve this please!
So, this is my code:

InvokingTask.java:

```
import java.util.Date;

import org.quartz.Job;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionContext;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionException;

public class InvokingTask implements Job {

    public void execute(JobExecutionContext jec) throws JobExecutionException {

        System.out.println("test --- "+new Date());
        //Aca pueden poner la tarea o el job que desean automatizar
        //Por ejemplo enviar correo, revisar ciertos datos, etc
    }

}
```

Scheduling.java:

```
import org.quartz.CronScheduleBuilder;
import org.quartz.JobBuilder;
import org.quartz.JobDetail;
import org.quartz.Scheduler;
import org.quartz.SchedulerException;
import org.quartz.SchedulerFactory;
import org.quartz.Trigger;
import org.quartz.TriggerBuilder;
import org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory;

public class Scheduling {

    private Scheduler horario;

    private void crearProgramacio() {

        try {

            SchedulerFactory factoria = new StdSchedulerFactory();
            horario = factoria.getScheduler();
            horario.start();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }

    }

    public void iniciarTarea() {

        if (this.horario == null) {
            this.crearProgramacio();
        }

        try {

            JobDetail job1 = JobBuilder.newJob(InvokingTask.class).withIdentity("job1", "group1").build();
            Trigger trigger1 = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity("cronTrigger1", "group1")
                    .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0/5 * * * * ?")).build();

            Scheduler scheduler1 = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
            scheduler1.start();
            scheduler1.scheduleJob(job1, trigger1);


        } catch (SchedulerException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

Test.java:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scheduling test = new Scheduling();
        test.iniciarTarea();
    }
}
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.motorbox.logic.Scheduling.iniciarTarea(Scheduling.java:41)
    at com.motorbox.logic.Test.main(Test.java:16)
```

Please, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I just realiced that I was using an old librery. I updated it and now it's working!!

Comment: A library that is public? Would you mind sharing that information? I have a same error with Quartz and am desperate to solve it too :-)